# Corners theorem in finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

The [corners theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corners_theorem) of Ajtai and Szemerédi states that if $A\subseteq[N]^2$ is *corner-free*, i.e. there are no $x,y,h\in\mathbb{N}$ with all of $(x,y),(x+h,y),(x,y+h)$ in $A$, then $|A|=o(N^2)$. The standard proof of this theorem is to apply the triangle removal lemma that follows from [Szemerédi's graph regularity lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma). The theorem is particularly useful because it implies Roth's theorem, which can also be proven directly using the regularity lemma.

If we let $r_3(S)$ be the maximum size of a subset of $S$ that is $3$-AP free, and $r_\angle(S)$ be the same except for corner-free, then Roth's theorem becomes $r_3([N])=o(N)$ and the corners theorem becomes $r_\angle([N])=o(N^2)$. The inequality $r_3([N])\leq\frac{r_\angle([N])}{N}$ shows that the corners theorem implies Roth's theorem.

The finite field setting $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ (with size $N=p^n$) is often used as a "sandbox" for applying methods to integers before applying them directly on the integers. For example, we have a similar theorem that $r_3(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(\frac{N}{\log N})$, which can be proven using Fourier analysis. This Fourier proof of Roth's theorem for finite fields can be modified to prove Roth's theorem over $\mathbb{N}$.

The inequality $r_3(\mathbb{F}_p^n)\leq\frac{r_\angle(\mathbb{F}_p^n)}{N}$ still holds, so a corners theorem for finite fields of the form $r_\angle(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(\frac{N^2}{\log N})$ would imply Roth's theorem for finite fields. Is there a known result of this form? I might expect such a proof to come in a Fourier form, similar to how the stronger version of Roth's theorem can be proven in a similar method. Perhaps such a Fourier proof would also produce a Fourier proof of the corners theorem over $\mathbb{N}$.

Even stronger, is there a known result of the form $r_\angle(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(c^{2n})$ for some $c<p$? This would, for the same reasons, imply that $r_3(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(c^n)$ for some $c<p$ (which is the subject of the [cap set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_set), resolved via the Croot-Lev-Pach polynomial method).

Comment: The question in your last paragraph attracts a lot of attention but is still open, as far as I know.

Answer (score 10):

Concerning your second question

> ...is there a known result of the form $r_\angle(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(c^{2n})$ for some $c<p$? This would, for the same reasons, imply that $r_3(\mathbb{F}_p^n)=O(c^n)$ for some $c<p$ (which is the subject of the [cap set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_set), resolved via the Croot-Lev-Pach polynomial method).

Not only is this not known, it is known that the methods that work for the cap set problem **do not** work for the corner-free problem. That is, a slice-rank based proof is impossible. The reason is that the slice-rank applies generally to upper bound  *induced matchings*, and there are large induced matchings in this graph.

Indeed, see [Theorem 8 of this paper by Christandl, Fawzi, Ta, and Zuiddam](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08262):

> **Theorem:** For any abelian group $G$, the hypergraph $H^{\boxtimes n}_{\text{corner},G}$ has an induced matching of size $|G|^{2n-o(n)}$.

This implies that the slice-rank of any tensor that "fits" the corner problem over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is always maximal, so no direct slice-rank proof is possible.